# Test class Code coverage gets varied

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Can any one let me know why the test class code coverage gets varied.

1)When I test individual testclass (controller) in the sandbox  the code coverage shows as 35% only .

2)when I Run all the test classes in the sandbox ,then the testclass(controller) shows as 48%.why is the variation occurs.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: A test class and a controller are not the same thing. The apex test class is code that should be testing some other code, such as a controller. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @ Jeremy Nottingham:Controller is the name of the test class.

Answer (score 4):

One or more methods of the controller are being called (maybe indirectly) by other test classes, so you get more coverage.

Using the Developer Console, you can discover which lines in the class were covered by which test classes.

Comment: :I do have doubt but when we move the  individual test class into production at that time it gets varied and the overall organization code coverage gets reduced less than 75% .Then how to improve the  overall organization code coverage.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: It is also ppssible that you are handling an error that is causing other code to not be executed to drop. Are you deploying anything that is enteractig with other code? Also if you run the test through mavens mate or eclipse the log will come back in one file so you can check for exceptions more easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform run all tests, then test methods from other test classes are covering your test class for controller and hence you get more coverage.

And for deployment, you need atleast 75% overall code coverage.for that check for all the classes in your org. Check if each class has test coverage of at least 75%. So it will cause overall coverage to increase.